# Javascript Output to Form Textarea not honoring line breaks on PC

Tags: javascript, jquery, line-breaks

I have a small web tool to extract URLs from a source of a web page. It processes them to an array of urls I cleverly stored in a variable called `urls` that I then insert with jQuery to a textarea (id `#links`), separated by double line breaks, so someone can copy.

I've tried joining by double `\n\n` and `\r\n\r\n`

```
$('#links').val(urls.join("\r\n\r\n"));
```

A user on a PC (I have Mac OS only) keeps saying they do not get line returns. I am rather stumped as to how to output to the text area ro put URLs on separate lines, separated by a blank line. This sure seemed easy.

This is the tool https://cogdog.github.io/storify-extractor/

Comment: use simple `<br/ >` tag

Comment: Guys, a <br> isnt going to look right in a textarea.

Comment: Works fine [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/jYaEWP?editors=1111)... And I'm on pc.

Comment: Works fine for me too (chrome, windows).  Find out what browser this guy has and ask him to send you a screenshot.

Comment: Are you sure that "Storify" provides an array? Try `console.log(typeof(urls));`

Comment: He uses Firefox and sent me a screenshot; it lacks line breaks in the text area, but when he copies it elsewhere it does have line breaks.

Comment: Storify does not provide an array; my script parses it with regex to find all the `data-element` parameters of the `<li>` items.